# Problem installing Chess-7 font

Tags: chessboard, chessfss

I am following instructions in `http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/chess/enpassant/README` to install Chess-7 font.

I use

```
ttf2pt1 -b Chess-7.TTF chess-7-board-raw
```

to create `chess-7-board-raw.pfb` file.

The following is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LSB,LSF,LSB1,LSB2,LSB3,LSBC1,LSBC2,LSBC3,LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\pdfmapfile{=chess-enpassant.map}

\begin{document}

\setchessboard{        
    showmover=false,
    labelleft=false,
    labelbottom=false,  
    boardfontencoding=LSB,
    boardfontfamily=chess-7
    }   
\newgame
\chessboard

\end{document}
```

The compiled document looks like

[image]

Compiling using pdflatex results in a number of warnings of the form

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./chess-7-board-raw.pfb): glyph `_d_10' undefined
```

There are number of warnings for other glyph's as well.
I am not sure how to fix this issue. Is the problem in `Chess-7.TTF` file or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry but I can't test now. But generally: the instructions are around 10 years old and things can change including glyph names (I even don't know if I still have a working ttf2pt1)

Comment: well I don't have a ttf2pt1 anymore. But if you make the pfb available to me, I can check the new names. Or open the pfb (or perhaps the afm if there is one) and try to guess the new names. You have to replace things like `/_d_38` in chess-7-board.enc